# View stats for sendgrid dynamic templates

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates, sendgrid-api-v2

I am using sendgrid to send transactional emails (dynamic templates) but can't figure out how to view the stats of emails opened, delivered etc. Is there a way GUI or API that I can use to view stats on my transactional emails?

Answer (score 6):

In the Activities feed page you can filter by Transactional Template Id. That might get you what you need.

Comment: this is very helpful. I was facing a similar issue and your solution saved a lot of time.

Comment: Is it also possible to see aggregates? Activity shows per email send.